# eXo Platform stuck at startup, after "Root container booted"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, webserver

I already posted in the support forum of the eXo community but didn't get any help from there.

I installed eXo platform on my server (Ubuntu 15.05) and after, on the second startup it just hangs on the last line of the console text I pasted below.. I tried a fresh install it makes no differences at all.

When I try to stop the program it crashes to sending back an error on the "pid". (I can't give you that since I'm having issues starting it right now.)

```
root@le33association:/usr/share/platform-community# ./start_eXo.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/platform-community
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/platform-community
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/platform-community/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
Using CLASSPATH:       :/usr/share/platform-community/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/platform-community/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/platform-community/lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/platform-community/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/platform-community/lib/janino-2.6.1.jar:/usr/share/platform-community/lib/commons-compiler-2.6.1.jar:/usr/share/platform-community/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/platform-community/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
2016-01-25 05:08:41,385 | INFO  | Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.63 [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,389 | INFO  | Server built:          Jun 30 2015 08:08:33 UTC [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,389 | INFO  | Server number:         7.0.63.0 [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,389 | INFO  | OS Name:               Linux [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,389 | INFO  | OS Version:            4.2.0-23-generic [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,390 | INFO  | Architecture:          amd64 [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,390 | INFO  | Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,390 | INFO  | JVM Version:           1.7.0_91-b02 [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,390 | INFO  | JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,391 | INFO  | CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/share/platform-community [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,391 | INFO  | CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/platform-community [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,391 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/platform-community/conf/logging.properties [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,392 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Dnop [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,392 | INFO  | Command line argument: -DEXO_TOMCAT_UNPACK_WARS=false [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,392 | INFO  | Command line argument: -DEXO_DEV=false [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,392 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Dexo.jcr.session.tracking.active=false [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,393 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Xms512m [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,393 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Xmx3g [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,393 | INFO  | Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=256m [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,393 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,394 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,394 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Duser.language=en [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,394 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Duser.region=US [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,394 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,395 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,395 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Dexo.profiles=all [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,395 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Dexo.conf.dir=/usr/share/platform-community/gatein/conf [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,395 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Dgatein.conf.dir=/usr/share/platform-community/gatein/conf [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,396 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Djava.security.auth.login.c/usr/share/platform-community/conf/jaas.conf [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,396 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Dexo.data.dir=/usr/share/platform-community/gatein/data [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,396 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Dexo.jcr.data.dir=/usr/share/platform-community/gatein/data/jcr [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,396 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Dexo.jcr.storage.data.dir=/usr/share/platform-community/gatein/data/jcr/values [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,396 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Dexo.jcr.index.data.dir=/usr/share/platform-community/gatein/data/jcr/index [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,397 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Dlogback.c/usr/share/platform-community/conf/logback.xml [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,397 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Djavax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLOutputFactoryImpl [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,397 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,397 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Djavax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.XMLEventFactoryImpl [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,398 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,398 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,398 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/platform-community/endorsed [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,398 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/platform-community [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,399 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/platform-community [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,399 | INFO  | Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/platform-community/temp [o.a.c.startup.VersionLoggerListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:41,399 | INFO  | The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib [o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:42,029 | INFO  | Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080"] [o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:42,076 | INFO  | Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-0.0.0.0-8009"] [org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:42,091 | INFO  | Initialization processed in 2671 ms [org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:46,031 | INFO  | checkpointClose start [hsqldb.db.HSQLDB5259F422F7.ENGINE<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:46,032 | INFO  | checkpointClose synched [hsqldb.db.HSQLDB5259F422F7.ENGINE<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:46,610 | INFO  | checkpointClose script done [hsqldb.db.HSQLDB5259F422F7.ENGINE<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:46,629 | INFO  | checkpointClose end [hsqldb.db.HSQLDB5259F422F7.ENGINE<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:47,090 | INFO  | Database closed [hsqldb.db.HSQLDB5259F422F7.ENGINE<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:50,349 | INFO  | Starting service Catalina [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:50,349 | INFO  | Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.63 [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine<main>]
2016-01-25 05:08:50,401 | INFO  | Deploying web application archive /usr/share/platform-community/webapps/wiki.war [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig<localhost-startstop-1>]
2016-01-25 05:08:52,148 | INFO  | At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. [org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig<localhost-startstop-1>]
2016-01-25 05:08:52,263 | INFO  | Building root container [exo.kernel.container.RootContainer<localhost-startstop-1>]
2016-01-25 05:08:52,363 | INFO  | Override exo-conf directory '/usr/share/platform-community/exo-conf' with location '/usr/share/platform-community/gatein/conf' [exo.kernel.container.J2EEServerInfo<localhost-startstop-1>]
2016-01-25 05:08:52,364 | INFO  | Active profiles [tomcat, all] [exo.kernel.container.RootContainer<localhost-startstop-1>]
2016-01-25 05:08:52,654 | INFO  | Skipping configuration file file:/usr/share/platform-community/gatein/conf/exo.properties. File doesn't exist. [o.e.p.c.c.ExtendedPropertyConfigurator<localhost-startstop-1>]
2016-01-25 05:08:52,655 | INFO  | Skipping configuration file file:/usr/share/platform-community/gatein/conf/upgrade.properties. File doesn't exist. [o.e.p.c.c.ExtendedPropertyConfigurator<localhost-startstop-1>]
2016-01-25 05:08:52,655 | INFO  | Using property file jar:file:/usr/share/platform-community/lib/platform-extension-config-4.3.0-RC2-1.jar!/conf/platform/configuration.properties to set configuration properties. [o.e.p.c.c.ExtendedPropertyConfigurator<localhost-startstop-1>]
2016-01-25 05:08:52,701 | INFO  | Root container is built (build time 437ms) [exo.kernel.container.RootContainer<localhost-startstop-1>]
2016-01-25 05:08:52,702 | INFO  | Set the top container in its context [exo.kernel.container.ExoContainerContext<localhost-startstop-1>]
2016-01-25 05:08:52,702 | INFO  | Root container booted [exo.kernel.container.RootContainer<localhost-startstop-1>]</localhost-startstop-1></localhost-startstop-1></localhost-startstop-1></localhost-startstop-1></localhost-startstop-1></localhost-startstop-1></localhost-startstop-1></localhost-startstop-1></localhost-startstop-1></localhost-startstop-1></localhost-startstop-1></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main></main>
```

Comment: For some reason webapps are not deployed (I only see wiki.war in your logs whereas is should deploy much more webapps). Can you give more information about your environment please ? How did you install it ? Did you just unzip it and run it ?

Answer (score 1):

Hello,

I've answered to your message on the [eXo Community Forum](https://community.exoplatform.com/portal/intranet/forum/topic/topic76fd65369e4534521f2e43fe4e5ae787).


We have reproduced and fixed this error in the **latest eXo Platform Community Docker image**.

It's an entropy problem.
Under Linux, entropy generator (used by UUID generator) make use of /dev/random by default. If this device is blocked, it can slow down and lock the JVM.
It's advised to use the unblocking entropy generator, /dev/urandom, instead by adding **-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom** to Java parameters.

To fix it on your installation, you just have to:

1. rename $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv-customize.sample.sh to  **$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv-customize.sh**
2. add the following line at the end of this file**:**

   ```
   CATALINA_OPTS="${CATALINA_OPTS} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"
   ```

As we've updated the **latest eXo Platform Community Docker image for eXo Platform 4.3**, you can use it like below:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name=exo exoplatform/exo-community:latest
```

Let me know if it's ok for you.
Thanks